# Sort on two fields in MongoDB simultaneously

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am currently developing a solution in MongoDB, where i have two different data schemas in the same collection. The problem is that some of the data has different field names. For example:
In one of the contracts a date is named: `date_at`, but in another type of contract it is just named `date`.

So the question is: **How do i sort on one field, and if it is not present in the document, sort on the other instead?**

Currently i am trying to make a query such as this:

```js
db.collection('contracts').aggregate([
  {$project: {
    date_at: [ $ifNull: ['$date', null]
  }},
  {$sort: { date_at: -1 }}
]);
```

But it doesn't seem to work. Hopefully one of you will be able to help me. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[$ifNull](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/)  is your solution :

taking the following documents set :

```
[
  {
    _id: 1,
    name: "c"
  },
  {
    _id: 2,
    name: "a"
  },
  {
    _id: 3,
    lastname: "b"
  },
  {
    _id: 4,
    name: "d"
  },
]
```

The following query will project name, or lastname if name doesn't exist, as name, and sort by name on second stage :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      name: {
        $ifNull: [
          "$name",
          "$lastname"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      name: 1
    }
  }
])
```

Will result in :

```
[
  {
    "_id": 2,
    "name": "a"
  },
  {
    "_id": 3,
    "name": "b"
  },
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "name": "c"
  },
  {
    "_id": 4,
    "name": "d"
  }
]
```

$ifNull takes an array of 2 params : if first is null or not present, then use the second.

Comment: Thanks a lot dude! I couldn't quite figure it out!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to create a **compound index**.

A compound index consists of a single index which references multiple fields.

NOTE. It is important that the order of the fields in a compound index correspond to the order logic of your query's sort (see [Sort Order](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/sort-results-with-indexes/#sort-on-multiple-fields)).

Example:

Create compound index:

```
db.data.createIndex( { a:1, b: 1, c: 1, d: 1 } )
```

Find data with sort:

```
db.data.find().sort( { a: -1, b: -1 } )
```

More Info:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/sort-results-with-indexes/#sort-on-multiple-fields

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/sort-results-with-indexes/